# How to solve this?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let V be the space of $n\times1$ matrices over $F$ and let $W$ be the space of $m\times1$ matrices over $F$. Let $A$ be a fixed $m\times n$ matrix over $F$ and let $T$ be the linear transformation from $V$ into $W$ defined by $T(X)=AX$. Prove that $T$ is the zero transformation, then $A$ is the zero matrix.

I believe that there is something wrong. Is possible to conclude that $A=0$ and the fact that $ AX =  0$?

Comment: The space of $\;n\times 1\;$ matrices over a field $\;\Bbb F\;$ is usually denoted by $\;\Bbb F^n\;$ , and if one wants to be sure it is possible to state the vectors will be column ones.

Comment: See also: [Showing that a matrix $A$ is zero iff $T(X) := AX$ is the zero transformation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1265929)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $v_1,\dots,v_n$ and $w_n,\dots,w_m$ be the standard basis vectors, i.e. all vectors of the form $(0,\dots,0,1,0\dots,0)^T$ of the appropriate size.

Note that the $i,j$ entry of $A$ must be given by the dot product $w_i \cdot (Av_j)$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose

$$A=(a_{ij})_{1\le i\le m\,,\,1\le j\le n}$$

Now, if $\;T\;$ is the zero transformation, then if we denote by $\;e_k\;$ the element in $\;\Bbb F^n\;$ with all its entries zero *except* the $\;k$-th one which is $\;1\;$ , we get

$$Te_k=T\begin{pmatrix}0\\\ldots\\1\\\ldots\\0\end{pmatrix}:=(a_{ij})e_k=\begin{pmatrix}a_{1k}\\a_{2k}\\\ldots\\a_{ik}\\\ldots\\a_{mk}\end{pmatrix}$$

Since the above is the zero vector in $\;\Bbb F^n\;$ , you get that all the $\;k$-th column in $\;A\;$ is zero.

Generalize.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $n$ vectors $X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n$ and note that
$$
A[X_1\ X_2\ \dots\ X_n]=[AX_1\ AX_2\ \dots\ AX_n]
$$
where $[X_1\ X_2\ \dots\ X_n]$ denotes the matrix having the stated columns. By hypothesis,
$$
A[X_1\ X_2\ \dots\ X_n]
$$
is the zero matrix. But if you consider a suitable choice of the vectors, so that
$$
[X_1\ X_2\ \dots\ X_n]
$$
is the identity matrix, you're done.