# Showing that a matrix $A$ is zero iff $T(X) := AX$ is the zero transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be the space of $n \times 1$ matrices over $F$ and let $W$ be the space of all $m \times 1$ matrices over $F$. Let $A$ be a fixed $m \times n$ matrix over $F$ and $T$ be a linear transformation $T : V\to W$ defined by $T(X)=AX$. Prove that $T$ is the zero transformation if and only if $A$ is the zero matrix.

**My try**

1. I am thinking that if I set the matrix $A=0$, that is, the $0$ matrix, then the $0$ matrix times any other matrix will be zero. I don't know whether this is right or not. Can someone please check it?
2. What if I had to prove the converse of this? How am I supposed to prove that?

Answer (score 1):

Your argument for the $[\Longleftarrow]$ part is correct. This is because $0\cdot a=0$ for all $a\in F$, $0+0+\cdots+0=0$ and $AX$ has entries consisting of additions and multiplications of these types when $A=0$.

For $[\Longrightarrow]$, consider taking $X$ as the vectors $e_i$, where $e_i$ is the vector consisting of $1$ as its $i$-th entry and $0$ for its other entries.
Taking $X=e_i$ will show that the $i$-th column of $A$ is $0$. Hence $A=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Your argument for $(\Leftarrow)$ is correct.

For the converse, $(\Rightarrow)$, one quick option is to prove the contrapositive: Since $A$ is nonzero, it has some nonzero row, say the $j$th one. If we denote the transpose of this row by $X$ (so that the row, regarded as a row vector, is $X^T$) then by definition the $j$th entry of $T(X) = AX$ is $X^T X$, which is just the standard dot product of $X$ with itself; since $X$ is nonzero, so is $X^T X$, so $T(X) \neq 0$ and hence $T$ is not the zero transformation.